# Triphase servo motors and amplifiers from different manufacturers: can they work together?

Tags: amplifier, control, servo

I'm a newbie here and more generally in electronics. I'm offered used industrial equipment's that would theoretically be of great use for several projects we have in our workshop. More specifically, included are AC servo motors and a set of amplifiers and control. But it seems the motors were parts of different machines and are of different brands.

Is there any kind of interchangeability between such components from different manufacturers so that it would be reasonably feasible to get them to work together?

If the answer is yes, I would start investigating for relevant sources of information, or online guidance, on the net; mostly that I have been offered more units in case I'm interested. Otherwise, I would avoid investing too much time in trying to use this equipment.

I've spent time searching for info about this on the net but ended up with conflicting answers.

Wiki says: "Although many servo motors require a drive specific to that particular motor brand or model, many drives are now available that are compatible with a wide variety of motors ..." but I didn't find any lead about that, only brand-to-brand combinations. Furthermore, the best solution in my case would be to bundle my motors and driver together (if possible).

Any information greatly appreciated.

ps1: some pics of the equipment's attached

ps2: I am located off the beaten tracks and closest official technical support is 700 km away.. ;)

[image: motors]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That would be also a challenge for most experienced engineer. The motors can differ in the feedback type: resolver, sin/cos, incremental, absolute, ...then the voltage/current rating, inductance, resistance.

You would need to be highly skilled to tune the current controller to match each motor. In practice, you attach the motor which is declared to be compatible with the servo drive and the pre-settings are already available by means of downloading/programming the servo drive.

Comment: That pretty much confirms my fears. Thanks. I'll give up matching the current components together. Meanwhile I'll go looking for these drivers supposed to fit various models of motors.